# Open mail in python

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to do a python code to open a Mailbox and reading them..

All I can do for now is to do a connection to a mailbox (a gmail or a hotmail for example) and getting my mail but I got something like this :

I think it's the header of the mail.

```
Delivered-To: ************@gmail.comReceived: by 10.70.102.67 with SMTP id fm3csp1378385pdb;        Mon, 27 Apr 2015 09:20:55 -0700 (PDT
)X-Received: by 10.68.217.106 with SMTP id ox10mr23174020pbc.21.1430151654873;        Mon, 27 Apr 2015 09:20:54 -0700 (PDT)Return-Path: <b
05524c6220********2047=gmail.com@bounce.twitter.com>Received: from spruce-goose-ab.twitter.com (spruce-goose-ab.twitter.com. [199.59.150
.71])        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 6si30521501pds.59.2015.04.27.09.20.54        for <**********@gmail.com>
```

But well here's my problem, this thing I got is not really what I want. I want to know if there is a way to see it clearly, just like a real mail box but in my terminal.

Here's the code by the way :

```
import getpass, poplib

user = '**********@gmail.com'
Mailbox = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.googlemail.com', '995')
Mailbox.user(user)
Mailbox.pass_('*********')
numMessages = 1 #len(Mailbox.list()[1]) #Only one mail                
file = open("mail.html", "w")
for i in range(numMessages):
    for msg in Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1]:
        file.write(msg)
file.close
Mailbox.quit()
```

Comment: Says https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html#mailbox-objects "The Mailbox class defines an interface and is not intended to be instantiated. Instead, format-specific subclasses should inherit from Mailbox and your code should instantiate a particular subclass."

Comment: According to OP code , `Mailbox` is not instantiated directly, he is instantiating it using - `Mailbox = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.googlemail.com', '995')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of retr() is a tuple (response, ['line', ...], octets) of
which you are keeping the list of lines.  In the example given at the end of [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html)
they show

```
for j in M.retr(i+1)[1]:
    print j
```

which you have converted to

```
for msg in Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1]:
    file.write(msg)
```

The difference is that print adds a newline, and your write does not.
Just add a "\n" after every write().

However, I agree that you only seem to have the headers...